# Vue.js passing different data as props to child components via router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a nested router in my vue app.

My `router/index.js`:

```
{
    path: "/parent",
    name: "Parent",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "parent" */ "../views/Parent.vue"),

    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      name: 'ChildOne',
      components: {
        nestedview: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "child-one" */ "../views/ChildOne.vue"),
      }
    },
    {
      path: "child-two",
      name: "ChildTwo",
      components: {
        nestedview: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "child-two" */ "../views/ChildTwo.vue"),
      }
    }]
  },
```

Parent component template (I use pug):

```
  router-view(
    name="nestedview",
    :functionOne="functionOne",
    :functionTwo="functionTwo",
    :functionThree="functionThree",
  )
```

The thing is that I need `functionOne`, `functionTwo` and `functionThree` only in the `ChildOne` component, where I pass them as props. In the `ChildTwo` component I need only the `functionOne` which I pass as a prop, but in my browser in the source code I can see that the other two are somehow passed as parameters `functionTwo="function () { [native code] }"` and `functionThree="function () { [native code] }"` of the root element of the component.

The question is, is there a way to pass from the Parent component to the Child components different data as props if these components are technically not child components of the Parent, but are rendered via the nested router?

Comment: I think you should use mixins instead of props to pass functions.

Answer (score 1):

`v-bind` automatically binds an attribute if a property is not found.

A quick fix is to use `v-bind`'s [`.prop` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) so that the binding only tries to set the component prop if it exists (otherwise, nothing is bound):

```
router-view(
  name="nestedview",
  :functionOne.prop="functionOne",
  :functionTwo.prop="functionTwo",
  :functionThree.prop="functionThree",
)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/binding-props-fbb73?file=/src/views/Parent.vue:225-336)